# Fonts in a textbox?

Tags: html, css

In a normal textbox created in Rails by:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'chat_data', '', :rows => 30, :cols => 70 %>
```

is it possible to have fonts for the text, such as bolding and colouring? I'm using the textbox to store a chat session and want to make it more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 5):

I would forget `<textarea>`s completely. Output HTML into a `<div>` and use CSS to format your markup.

An example:

```
<div class="chatbox">
    <p><span class="name">Oli:</span> My message</p>
    <p><span class="name">Oli:</span> My message</p>
    <p><span class="name">Oli:</span> My message</p>
    <p><span class="name">Oli:</span> My message</p>
</div>
```

with some of the following formatting:

```
.chatbox {overflow:auto;width:500px;height:200px}
.chatbox p {}
.chatbox .name {font-weight:bold}
```

All fairly simple but you can dial it up if you know how. (Note: width and height must be fixed for overflow to work).

Comment: And how would I get a scrollable text area?

Comment: That's the div. Give it overflow:auto and you'll have a scroll-bar when it's got too much content. You certainly need to know a bit of CSS but that's true with either route.

Comment: Why are there two <span>'s and just one </span>?

Comment: My bad. *edits* I was going to go for two spans per paragraph but realised it probably wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. [WYSIWYG editors](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/wysiwyg-html-edit/) in HTML use a nifty trick involving an `editable` attributed element, not a `textarea`.